# how to change a global variable inside a function in node.js

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js

so i'm working on node.js and i have a global variable which must be changed inside a function and then checked outside it again.

here is my code:

```
let res = 0;

con.query(check, function(err, result, res) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
    if (result != null) res = 0;
    else res = 1;
});
```

so the variable i want to change is "res" however, the value is never set and the variable is always 0. how can i change it?

Comment: possible dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: remove 'res' in your callback params

Comment: Tried that already. Sounds good, doesn't work.